# how to pass id to controller in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a `model` called image with an attribute called `PostID` and another `model` called post. In the list `view`, When the user clicks on a post to add images to it, it passes the `PostID` via a `HtmlActionLink`

`@Html.ActionLink("Add Images", "AddImages", new { id = item.PostID })`

It works fine, but I need to save that `PostId` in the image `Model` as well.

```
    public ActionResult AddImages(int id)
    {
        ImageViewModel images = new ImageViewModel();
        images.PostID = id;           
        return View(images);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddImages(ImageViewModel image, HttpPostedFileBase images)
    {            
        Image newImage = new Image();
        newImage.PostID = image.PostID;
        return View("Index");
    }
```

This way it will not work, when it saves, the value of `PostID` is 0. I also tried using `ViewBag`, but no luck so far. In the AddImages `View` there is no `TextBoxFor` or anything for the `PostID` attribute as it is not to be set or seen by the users.

Comment: Create an input on the view to store the id of the model. Usually a hidden input.

Comment: If you rename your view model property to `ID` instead of `PostID `, then you do not need to do anything - it will be added as a route value in the forms `action` attribute (no `HiddenFor()` is required in the view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get `PostID` in the HttpPost action,you should add input field for `PostId` in the view's form tag.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.PostId)
```

Comment: Is this method safe or the best way to do it?

Comment: According to me it is the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `PostID` is not set by the user, but you still need to put it in the `<form>` so that it will be postback to the server in an `HttpPost`. Usually, we use a `hidden field` for it. Some thing like:

```
<form>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.PostID)

    <!-- Other fields here -->
</form>
```